# Strange Operation contract behaviour in wcf

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have one WCF rest service operation contract which internally calls another service.
While making a call to another service, It adds certificate and makes a call to the other service.

My operation contract is like below

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/report/videodata/{component}/{count}")]
        ServiceResponse CallcomponentHandler(string component, string count);
```

and my implementation is like below

```
public ServiceResponse CallcomponentHandler(string component, string count)
    {
       //Making HTTP Get Request to another service
        return utility.GetResponse(Url);           
    }
```

But when I am trying to consume this Operation from internet explorer, This is getting called multiple times.

Please note the other service has  async method.

I tried adding maxReceivedMessageSize,maxStringContentLength in web.config file but still not able to resolve this.

Below is my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Video.GetDetails" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="rest" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Video.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
                 sendTimeout="10:15:00"
                 openTimeout="10:15:00"
                 receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="StreamedRequest" >
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
        </binding>
        <!-- For Cyber Source bindings-->
        <binding name="ITransactionProcessor" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824" maxNameTableCharCount="1073741824"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <!--Cyber Source bindings ends here-->
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: *But when I am trying to consume this Operation from internet explorer, This is getting called multiple times.* It's not like Chrome with its pre-rendering where it will connect to a site before you push Enter in the omnibox? i.e. From the run dialog `iexplore.exe http://yourwebsite/call/6` exhibits the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes it shows the same behavior. Even I have created one small client application to consume this service. There also I am finding same behavior !!!

Comment: Does the second service call the first one?

Comment: No it just returns service response.

Comment: Well break out the debugger and inspect [`OperationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) for the first and then second calls.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to add certificates to the request and route to another service and whatever response comes from that return to the client. Is there any other better way I can follow ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40856/discussion-between-ppm-and-ta-speot-is)